# How to get count of product pairings per order?

Tags: r, count, permutation

If I have a table of generic order transactions in **R**:

```
order_id   product_id   value
1000       A            100
1000       C            55
1000       D            75
1001       B            85
1001       A            35
1001       D            75
1002       B            70
1002       E            20

structure(list(order_id = c(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1001L, 1001L, 
1001L, 1002L, 1002L), product_id = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L,1L, 4L, 2L, 5L), 
.Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), 
value = c(100L, 55L, 75L, 85L, 35L, 75L, 70L, 20L)), .Names = c("order_id","product_id", "value"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

How would I get the count and/or average/summed value of product pairings over order_id, like:

```
product_id_one    product_id_two     count
A                 B                  1
A                 C                  1
A                 D                  2
A                 E                  0
B                 C                  0
B                 D                  1
B                 E                  1
C                 D                  1
C                 E                  0
D                 E                  0
```

or

```
product_id_one    product_id_two     value_average
A                 B                  175
A                 C                  55
A                 D                  142.5
A                 E                  0
B                 C                  0
B                 D                  160
B                 E                  90
C                 D                  130
C                 E                  0
D                 E                  0
```

except just looping over it or some similar iterative approach? Order of product ids should not be important.

Comment: Isn't there 3 order_id

Comment: I aim to count the number a pairing appears in unique order ids, not the amount of order_ids itself, i.e. "how often did product A and B get ordered together"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution **(UPDATED)**:

```
require(data.table)
mydf <- structure(list(order_id = c(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1001L, 1001L, 
                                1001L, 1002L, 1002L), product_id = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
                                                                               1L, 4L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), 
                   value = c(100L, 55L, 75L, 85L, 35L, 75L, 70L, 20L)), .Names = c("order_id", 
                                                                                   "product_id", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                               -8L))
mydf <- data.table(mydf,key="order_id")
mydf2 <- mydf[mydf,allow.cartesian=TRUE]
mydf2 <- mydf2[product_id!=i.product_id]
mydf2[,idx:=.I]
mydf2[,firstsecond:=paste0(min(as.character(product_id),as.character(i.product_id)),"_",max(as.character(product_id),as.character(i.product_id))),by=idx]
mydf2 <- mydf2[,.N,by=.(firstsecond,order_id,value)][,N:=NULL]
mydf3 <- mydf2[,.(count=length(unique(order_id)),value_average=sum(value)/length(unique(order_id))),by=firstsecond]
mydf3[,c("product1","product2"):=tstrsplit(firstsecond,"_")]
# firstsecond count value_average product1 product2
# 1:         A_C     1         155.0        A        C
# 2:         A_D     2         142.5        A        D
# 3:         C_D     1         130.0        C        D
# 4:         A_B     1         120.0        A        B
# 5:         B_D     1         160.0        B        D
# 6:         B_E     1          90.0        B        E
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: This brings me quite a step further. Two smaller issues:
• duplicates are listed (AD & DA) and • this is the average per order position value (i.e. (100 + 75 + 35 + 75) / 4), not the average per order value ((175 + 110) / 2); I can figure out the former, but how would you solve the latter?

Comment: @KarstenSender I have updated the solution. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Pretty perfect. Thanks a ton, I will work through the code.

Answer (score 0):

From the example data you give, I cannot see any association between product_id_one:A and product_id_two:B to the count or average. Could you perhaps add a bit more details?

Otherwise, assuming that you want to aggregate per order_id, I can suggest using data.table for it.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
#
dd <- data.frame(order_id = c(1000, 1000, 1000, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002),
                 product_id = c('A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'E'),
                 value = c(100, 55, 75, 85, 35, 75, 70, 20))
#
setDT(dd)
dgrouped <- dd %>% group_by(order_id, product_id) %>% summarize(count = n(), value_average = mean(value))
#
```

If you are looking for associations, you may want to look at the `apriori` algorithms, `arules` package.